# python - sys.argv and flag identification

Tags: python, arguments, sys

when I accept arguments how do I check if two show up at the same time without having a compound conditional

i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random, string
import mymodule
import sys

z = ' '.join(sys.argv[2:])
q = ''.join(sys.argv[3:])
a = ''.join(sys.argv[2:])
s = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
flags = sys.argv[1:5]

commands = [["-r", "reverse string passed next with no quotes needed."], ["-j", "joins arguments passed into string. no quotes needed."], ["--palindrome", "tests whether arguments passed are palindrome or not. collective."],["--rand","passes random string of 10 digits/letters"]]

try:
    if "-r" in flags:
        if "-j" in flags:
            print mymodule.reverse(q)
        if not "-j" in flags:
            print mymodule.reverse(z)

    if "-j" in flags:
        if not "-r" in flags:
            print a

    if "--palindrome" in flags: mymodule.ispalindrome(z)

    if (not "-r" or not "-j" or not "--palindrome") in flags: mymodule.say(s)

    if "--rand" in flags: print(''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters+"123456789") for f in range(10)]))

    if not sys.argv[1]: print mymodule.no_arg_error

    if "--help" in flags: print commands

except: print mymodule.no_arg_error
```

i just want to be able to say

if "-r" and "-j" in flags in no particular order:
      do whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also see `getopt`. It has a bit more terse syntax, and a complete example in docs.

Comment: what do you mean by terse syntax?

Comment: With optparse, you generally `add_option()` for each option. With getopt, you just write something  like `options, fnames = getopt("abf:")` and this handles `-a`, `-b` and `-f filename`.

Answer (score 7):

Something like

```
import optparse

p = optparse.OptionParser()
p.add_option('--foo', '-f', default="yadda")
p.add_option('--bar', '-b')
options, arguments = p.parse_args()

# if options.foo and options.bar ...
```

Comment: what does "default" do? just curious how I would incorporate that

Comment: new to python, not programming

Comment: and optparse seems to be deprecated so i'll go with getopt?

Comment: p.add_option('--year', '-y', default='2011'). -> blah.py --year 2010.

Comment: optparse is deprecated, but argparse is only introduced in 2.7. OS X, for example, runs 2.6 by default. If you are sure your audience is not on 2.6 anymore, you should go with argparse. Otherwise I'd recommend to stay with optparse, because it'll work on both 2.6 and 2.7.

Comment: From the doumentation: "Deprecated since version 2.7: The optparse module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the *argparse* module". `getopt` would be a step backwards.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) for this (or [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) if you're on Python 2.6.x or older).

Without a module you'd do this:

```
if "-r" in flags and "-j" in flags:
    do whatever
```

But I suggest you read the documentation for `argparse` and learn how to use it. You will be happy you did.

Comment: i am unfamiliar with optparse and that's a reason.

Answer (score 0):

'or' only can identify one,u should use 'a or b and c'

```
if (not "-r" or not "-j" and not "--palindrome") in flags: mymodule.say(s)
```